# Why my external style css sheet is not pulling through in IE but does in Chrome?

Tags: php, html, css

I have an `index.php` file with a `style.css` file within the exact same folder, I have tried linking my external style sheet into the html and it will NOT pull through. Please can someone take a look? This should be a simple thing however it's not pulling through my css when opening in Internet Explorer but it does however in Chrome?

`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PRCO304/style.css`

`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PRCO304/index.php`

In the top of the `index.php` file I have the below:

```
<head>
    <!-- CSS STYLING --> 
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

None of the styling is pulling through whatsoever.

[image: screenshots]

Comment: Try `./style.css` instead.

Comment: @Zera nope, doesn't make a difference ?

Comment: @Zera That is the weirdest thing, if I open the EXACT same `http://localhost:8888/PRCO304/` I get the styling pull through however in I.E the styling does not pull through?

Comment: Is there an error in DevTools (press `F12`) when in IE?

Comment: @K.Haydock Try to include the type attribute  `type='text/css'` and also include `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal I have added that in, then saved the css file, then refreshed in Chrome to see the styling had updated, refreshed in Safari and no updated styling?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a cache issue. Wipe the safari cache and load the page again.

Comment: Please try `CMD + ALT + E`.

Comment: It was INDEED a simple cache error!!!! Thank you to all of those who suggested cache :)

Comment: @K.Haydock Clear the catch of your browser as said by @Zera and again put `type='text/css'`, put `<!DOCTYPE html>` and always use **./** in `./style.css`

Comment: @AbhishekKamal May I ask why I would need the `./` please? So glad it was just a simple cache issue with safari

Comment: @K.Haydock because some browser may not be prepend `./` in path.. thats why

Comment: `./` references the current directory and `../` references the parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have some tips for you:

- make sure to place your css link inside 'head' tag
- using '/' to link your css file, if your index.php is in  `Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PRCO304` use `/PRCO304/style.css`
- clear your browser cache

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say when just seeing that, but Indeed, have you tried

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

since both in the same folder.

Comment: What difference would that make?